# Print/append repeated elements of array only once

Tags: python, arrays

I have a big list of strings appearing many times and I want a list of the same strings to appear only once.

An example with numbers would be:

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

and I want to get

```
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

What I tried is something like:

```py
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
[x for x in a if a.count(x) == 1]
[1, 3]
```

but this omits the duplicate numbers and takes only those appearing once.

Comment: `b = list(set(a))` or just `set(a)`, if set is enough

Comment: @AndrejKesely This should be used only If OP doesn't bother about order.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import collections
a = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8]
print([item for item, count in collections.Counter(a).items()])
```